# How to convert JSON string to custom object?

Tags: java, json

I've string like this (just )

```
"{\"username":\"stack\",\"over":\"flow\"}"
```

I'd successfully converted this string to JSON with

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject("{\"username":\"stack\",\"over":\"flow\"}");
```

I've a class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public String username;
    public String over;
}
```

How can I convert JSONObject into my custom MyClass object?

Comment: Look into Jackson or Gson, they both handle this sort of thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can implement a static method in `MyClass` that takes `JSONObject` as a parameter and returns a `MyClass` instance. For example:

```
public static MyClass convertFromJSONToMyClass(JSONObject json) {
    if (json == null) {
        return null;
    }
    MyClass result = new MyClass();
    result.username = (String) json.get("username");
    result.name = (String) json.get("name");
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to convert the object using JSONObject? without modifying the class

Answer (score 12):

you need Gson:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
final MyClass myClass = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyClass.class);
```

also what might come handy in future projects for you:
[Json2Pojo Class generator](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Comment: +1 Note: Gson is great for simple cases. If you need more control, have a look at Jackson.

Comment: @Goran Štuc One doubt, what is this GSON, is that better than JSON Object

Comment: Gson is an API which you can obtain here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/